# How to add text as background to html?

Tags: javascript, html, text, background

Right now I have a `div` with `line-wrap`, `word-break` and one line of randomly created 0s and 1s that are filling the background. It looks nice but the length is fixed and is too long/short in different screen sizes.

Is there a better way to go about this? I just want a nerdy background with 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your div with additional style properties.

```
.background {
  overflow-x: hidden; // hide scroll-x
  overflow-y: hidden; // hide scroll-y
  word-wrap: break-word; // word wrap text
  width:97%; // width > 97% absolut position div will overflow and cause screen scroll
  height:97%; // height > 97% absolut position div will overflow and cause screen scroll
  position: absolute; // this way the div will act as background and it will  not interfier with the rest of the components in the html
}
```

You can play & test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/fb3yLj8h/1/

Comment: Thank you, the fiddle helped me track the error. The 'height' attribute did not work in my project but in the fiddle. The reason was because I did not specify the height in the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use position property  *position: absolute* for text and text wrapper property *position : relative;*

Answer (score 0):

To full screen a text area :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <body>
         <textarea name="text1" style="width: 100%;height: 100%"></textarea>
      </body>
   </html>
```

if you want to be a input(use can't edite size):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <body>
      <input type="search"  style="width: 100%;height: 100%" >
     </body>
   </html>
```